# How do you find the zero vector for this vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let  = ℝ. For ,  ∈  and  ∈ ℝ define vector addition by  ⊞  =  +  + 3 and scalar multiplication  ⊡  =  + 3 − 3. It can be shown that  is a vector space under the operations ⊞ and ⊡ over the scalar field ℝ.

How do you find the zero vector?

Comment: $-3$ is the zero vector.

Comment: In the future, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical expressions.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you very much!

Comment: @amd Will do, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** On any vector space $V$, the zero vector is the only vector $v$ such that $v+v=v$.